# Initializer error message processing data

Tags: ios, initialization, swift4, xcode9

I have a class like this:

```
struct myData {
    let dataOne: String
    let dataTwo: String
}

extension myData{

static func doSomeThingWithThis(someData:Any) -> String {
.
.
.
.
return str // is returning a string
}


init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {

        guard let dataOne = dict["someKey"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
guard let dataTwo = myData.doSomeThingWithThis(someData: dict["anotherKey"]) else{
            return nil
        }
self.init(
            dataOne: dataOne,
            dataTwo: dataTwo,
        )
}
```

But my problem in this line:

```
guard let dataTwo = myData.doSomeThingWithThis(someData: dict["anotherKey"]) else{
            return nil
        }
```

Xcode is compelling with the following errors/warnings:

[image]
I have try different this like this:

```
guard let dataTwo = myData.doSomeThingWithThis(someData: dict["anotherKey"]as? String) else{
            return nil
        }
```

or this:

```
guard let dataTwo = myData.doSomeThingWithThis(someData: dict["anotherKey"]as? String) else{
            return nil
        }
```

But Xcode still complains. Any of you knows how can I fix this error/warning?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since `doSomeThingWithThis(someData:Any) -> String` returns a `String` rather than an optional, you cannot (and do not need to) use it in a guard statement.

Comment: can you please provide an example? because I change the signature of the function to (someData:Any) -> String? and now is complaining about  "Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any"

Comment: You might want to post that as a separate question. Comments really aren't the proper place for new/changed questions.